# Javascript(jquery) conflicts in asp application

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need advice, best practices. I have some functionality in my application which is required external javascript/jquery. I just tried to implement another component to my application which is using also  javascript/jquery but different.

The problem is they work perfectly separate, but cannot work together. I assumed some conflicts going on behind. I tried to trace it with firebug nothing to show as errors. But it's braking somewhere for sure.

I don't have a lot of experience of debugging client side scripts.

It would be great if someone suggest the best way how to debug, maybe trace or just how to find what causing conflict between those scripts.

Each of component has more than five, three external javascript files so it's no way for me to publish code here.

Comment: What components are you trying to use together? Can you at least post the JavaScript you're using on your page and the names of the external libraries?

Comment: It's a custom javascript, and latest jquery, jquery ui libraries. I would love to post code examples but it so many external files I just don't know where can be the problem. So I need to start debugging I think to find out where exactly the problem :(

Comment: Well, your first step should be looking at the code that doesn't work. So like if something is supposed to happen and doesn't, try stepping through it in firebug (put a breakpoint on the appropriate spot and then step through it and see what happens at each step).

Comment: Do you know good example how to use firebug to debug javascript code?

Comment: Could you explain what you'd expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Use Firefoxes FireBug to find the error...then post that code.